# How to create one common playbook-wide writeable variable in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a playbook to create many user accounts across many servers. At the end I want to get output with credentials sorted by username.

I used set_fact with run_once but it seems that defined variable is not playbook-wide.

main.yml

```
- name: Create users
  import_tasks: creation_task.yml
```

creation_task.yml

```
- name: Init variable for creds
  set_fact:
    creds: []
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true

- name: Create specific users
  include: create.yml
  with_items:
    - input_data
    - .......   

- name: Print output creds
  debug: var=creds
  run_once: true
```

create.yml

```
- name: some actions that actually create users
....

- name: add creds to list
  set_fact:
    creds: "{{ creds + [ {'hostname': inventory_hostname,'username':item.name,'password':password.stdout} ]}}"

- name: add splitter to list
  set_fact:
     creds: "{{ creds + [ '-----------------------------------------------------' ]}}"
```

This is actually working but i get output sorted by server because (as I think) every host reports his version of "creds" variable.

I'd like to create one variable that will be visible and writeable across all nested plays. So output would be sorted by input data but not hostname. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the following syntax, to fetch a variable set from a specific host via [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#caching-facts):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups['my_host_name']|map('extract',hostvars,'my_variable_name')|list|first }}"
    when: groups['my_host_name']|map('extract',hostvars,'my_variable_name')|list|first|length > 0
```

Then, you can loop over your hostnames to create an array of values and sort them.

Though, printing all servers hostnames, users & plain text passwords in a text file seems to be a security risk.